# Laravel SESSION expired 419 and auto redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.8

So I have this weird problem after I've uploaded my laravel project on a shared hosting. When ever I make any post request is responding with 419. FYI @csrf is included in each form. Everything is working fine on my localhost. I've tried to change the session driver but I had the same response too. Another thing when I ever I call a get request, laravel will redirect me back to the same page. [image]

[image]

**EDIT**
I've contacted my host support, they said that the error is coming from the Mod_security firewall of their shared server, and based on the logs they pulled up, they said the rule ID it generated is globally blocked on their servers. What are the alternative solutions?

Comment: Try checking permissions to the `storage/framework/sessions` directory

Comment: You could also contact the hosting company and explain the issue. It could be that they have some specific setup that requires you to do something in your app.

Comment: I've checked the permission in sessions directory, it's 7555.

Comment: I've contacted my host support, they said that the error is coming from the Mod_security firewall of their shared server, and based on the logs they pulled up, they said the rule ID it generated is globally blocked on their servers. What should I do now?

Comment: Not sure about the answer of your hosting provider. 
Did you check the if is not a problem with the timestamp between your server and the browser?
I mean you are generating expired sessions.

Comment: Did you clear the cache after uploading to the shared hosting server?  `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Try to disable mode security from admin panel (cpanel) for your website.

Comment: I've clear the app cache and I've regenerated the session key. Nothing has changed same issue.